# How do I know when X server has completed the drawing?

Tags: c++, graphics, xlib

Suppose I want to draw rectangles one after another. How do I know when X server has completed drawing one rectangle? Is there a way to get any confirmation from X server?
In the following code I draw the first rectangle at 500,500 and redraw the same rectangle in the expose handler. After that I draw a new rectangle at 1000,1000. The problem is that first rectangle was never drawn. How many times do I've to go through the Expose event handler? **HOW MANY TIMES IS ENOUGH?**

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/extensions/XTest.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    Display *disp;
    int screen;
    Window win;
    GC gc;

    disp = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    screen = DefaultScreen(disp);

    XColor color;
    Colormap colormap;
    char black[] = "#ffffff";
    colormap = DefaultColormap(disp, 0);
    XParseColor(disp, colormap, black, &color);
    XAllocColor(disp, colormap, &color);

    win = XCreateSimpleWindow(disp, RootWindow(disp, screen), 10, 
        10, 1500, 1500, 0, WhitePixel(disp, screen), color.pixel);

    XSizeHints    my_hints = {0};
    my_hints.flags  = PPosition | PSize;        
    my_hints.x      = 10;                        
    my_hints.y      = 10;
    my_hints.width  = 1500;
    my_hints.height = 1500;
    XSetNormalHints(disp, win, &my_hints);   
    XMapWindow(disp, win);  

    gc = XCreateGC(disp, win, 0, 0);

    XColor color1;
    Colormap colormap1;
    char red[] = "#000000";
    colormap1 = DefaultColormap(disp, 0);
    XParseColor(disp, colormap1, red, &color1);
    XAllocColor(disp, colormap1, &color1);  

    XSetForeground(disp, gc, color1.pixel);  

    XSelectInput(disp, win, ExposureMask);

    int x1 = 500;
    int x2 = 500;

    XEvent event;
    int i = 0;
    while(true){
        XDrawRectangle(disp, win, gc, x1, x1, 500, 500);
        XNextEvent(disp, &event);
        if(event.xany.window == win){
            if(event.type == Expose){
                cout << i << endl;
                XDrawRectangle(disp, win, gc, x1, x2, 500, 500);
            }
        }
        i++;
        x1 += 500;
        x2 += 500;
    }

    XFreeGC(disp, gc);
    XDestroyWindow(disp, win);
    XCloseDisplay(disp);
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
0
1
2
3
```

Comment: Rendering is separate and asynchronous.  If a window is uncovered it will get drawn at some time.  This is independent of the process running in the window. Getting all events is pointless, since that includes too many other things.  Instead, draw your rectangles with a timer at regular intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are expecting `XDrawRectangle()` to generate `Expose` events, but it will never happen, because this is not how it works. `Expose` events are generated when a window is mapped, resized, moved or when an obscuring window is unmapped, but not when drawing into a window. Actually, the only `Expose` event you are interesting in is the one generated by `XMapWindow()`. After receiving this first `Expose` event you know that window is mapped and can be drawn to. You should also call `XClearWindow()` before mapping a window to ensure it doesn't contain any garbage. Sometimes you may also want to check `if (event.xexpose.count == 0)` to process only the latest event in the queue, but it shouldn't be necessary in your example. Then just draw into the window and probably flush the buffer with `XFlush()` or `XSync()` after every draw. This should do what you want(I modified coordinates a little bit, but the principle is the same):

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/extensions/XTest.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Display* disp;
    int screen;
    Window win;
    GC gc;

    disp = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    screen = DefaultScreen(disp);

    XColor color;
    Colormap colormap;
    char black[] = "#ffffff";
    colormap = DefaultColormap(disp, 0);
    XParseColor(disp, colormap, black, &color);
    XAllocColor(disp, colormap, &color);

    win = XCreateSimpleWindow(disp,
                              RootWindow(disp, screen),
                              10,
                              10,
                              1500,
                              1500,
                              0,
                              WhitePixel(disp, screen),
                              color.pixel);

    XSizeHints my_hints = {0};
    my_hints.flags = PPosition | PSize;
    my_hints.x = 10;
    my_hints.y = 10;
    my_hints.width = 1500;
    my_hints.height = 1500;
    XSetNormalHints(disp, win, &my_hints);

    gc = XCreateGC(disp, win, 0, 0);

    XColor color1;
    Colormap colormap1;
    char red[] = "#000000";
    colormap1 = DefaultColormap(disp, 0);
    XParseColor(disp, colormap1, red, &color1);
    XAllocColor(disp, colormap1, &color1);

    XSetForeground(disp, gc, color1.pixel);

    XSelectInput(disp, win, ExposureMask);

    int x = 10;
    int y = 10;

    int i = 0;
    XClearWindow(disp, win); // Clear window from possible garbage
    XMapWindow(disp, win);
    XEvent event;

    while (true)
    {
        // Wait for window to be mapped
        XNextEvent(disp, &event);
        if (event.xany.window == win && event.type == Expose)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < 20; ++k)
    {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
        XDrawRectangle(disp, win, gc, x, y, 500, 500);
        XFlush(disp);
        ++i;
        x += 10;
        y += 10;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    }

    XFreeGC(disp, gc);
    XDestroyWindow(disp, win);
    XCloseDisplay(disp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I ran you code with the initial rectangle coordinates set to (x=0,y=0) and noticed that the first rectangle wasn't drawn. Your code generates 4 expose events. The rectangle at (x=0,y=0) is drawn when the second expose event is copied from the event queue to the XEvent structure. This could be accomplished with a counter in you "wait for window to be mapped" loop. No need to go through all those 4 expose events. I'm curious to know if you get the same result. Either way I'm accepting you answer.

Comment: In the example, did you only change the coordinates? I don't see the issue you are describing, I see only one `Expose` event and the first rectangle(0, 0) is always being drawn for me. According to the ancient "**Xlib programming manua**l": *The initial mapping of a top−level window is a special case, since the window’s visibility may be delayed by the window manager. For complicated reasons, an application must wait for the **first Expose event** before assuming that
its window is visible and drawing into it.*

Comment: I am not an X guru, but I can guess that maybe it is your DE performs some additional processing of the window generating additional Expose events. I am using a simple window manager without a full-featured DE, and the above example works as expected for me.

Comment: By the way, it seems that by **first expose event** they actually mean those with count == 0, and this explains why you are observing this strange behavior. In other words, always wait for `event.xexpose.count == 0`.